# Calling a .cmd script with os.system() doesn't work while the same command works in cmd terminal

Tags: python, operating-system, windows-terminal

I am trying to call a simple .cmd script with the parameters. In a windows terminal, the command below works:

```
cmd /c ""C:\Users\Mathieu\Desktop\NeuroDecode\scripts\nd_stream_recorder.cmd" "C:\Users\Mathieu\Desktop" "test""
```

However, using `os.system()` with the same command doesn't work.

```
os.system(r'cmd /c ""C:\Users\Mathieu\Desktop\NeuroDecode\scripts\nd_stream_recorder.cmd" "C:\Users\Mathieu\Desktop" "test""')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Could someone explain what my mistake is?

Additionally, here is a more complete code snippet  I use:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys

def start_recorder(directory, fname, neurodecode_path):
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        script = os.path.join(neurodecode_path, 'scripts', 'nd_stream_recorder.cmd')
        script = script.replace('/', '\\')
        if directory.endswith('/'):
            directory = directory[:-1]
        elif directory.endswith('\\'):
            directory = directory[:-2]
        directory = directory.replace('/', '\\')
        os.system(f'cmd /c ""{script}" "{directory}" "{fname}""')
    else:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    directory = 'C:\\Users\\Mathieu\\Desktop'
    fname = 'test'
    neurodecode_path = 'C:/Users/Mathieu/Desktop/NeuroDecode'
    
    start_recorder(directory, fname, neurodecode_path)
```

I will also add that the execution of this CMD call should occur in a separate/new terminal.

Comment: `>>> os.system(r'cmd /c ""C:\Users\xxx\py\stack-o\test.py" "C:\Users\xxx\py\stack-o" "test""')` works fine for me. Try `os.system(fr'cmd /c ""{script}" "{directory}" "{fname}""')` within your function.

Comment: @ack Indeed that command works. I ended up using `subprocess.call([script, directory, fname], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`. However, and I didn't notice earlier, but for both the `script` starts in my IDE terminal (spyder).. At least it works when not launched from the IDE!